The order of elements in a set when printed is not randomized
Why do I always get each element of a set printed out (by iterating over the set) in the same order, when, as said, it is a set and the elements should be unordered? Here is my code:
import random
my_set = set()
while len(my_set)<6:
    my_set.add(random.randint(1, 6))
for num in my_set:
    print(num)

I expected to print numbers 1 through 6, but in random order. It is supposed to be like a roll with a dice, but every number you roll is a unique one.

The order of Python sets is arbitrary, that's not the same as being random. You shouldn't rely on it to be anything at all. If you want random, use random - just list the six numbers and shuffle it.

@jonrsharpe Thank you for answering. But how does python determine when to use the ascending order and when just making it random?
